# Using PowerShell For Developing A Notification For An RSS News Alert

Tags: powershell, rss

I have this basic code that works fine for simple text message alert. Now, it would be handy to connect this script to alert the user whenever there is a new RSS feed from our ITS alert system.

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
 $objNotifyIcon = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
 $objNotifyIcon.Icon = [System.Drawing.SystemIcons]::Information
 $objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipIcon = "Info"
 $text = 'This is just a text'
 $objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipText = $text
 $objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = "Tip Title"
 $objNotifyIcon.Visible = $True
 $objNotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(30000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea for auto-close:

```
Function Get-BalloonTip {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$Text,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$Title,
    $Icon = 'Info',
    $Timeout = $10000
             )
    Process {
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    If ($PopUp -eq $null)  {
           $PopUp = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
                        }
             $Path = Get-Process -Id $PID | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path
             $PopUp.Icon = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon($Path)
             $PopUp.BalloonTipIcon = $Icon
             $PopUp.BalloonTipText = $Text
             $PopUp.BalloonTipTitle = $Title
             $PopUp.Visible = $true
             $PopUp.ShowBalloonTip($Timeout)
             Start-Sleep 5
             $PopUp.Visible = $false
                     } # End of Process
    } # End of Function

    Get-BalloonTip -Text "Hello" "Check This out"
```